# IronPython hosting caching imported module?

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython

I'm embedding IronPython in my application. Everything goes fine but I found that when I use `CreateScriptSourceFromFile` to execute a file, it seems that IronPython cached other imported  module.

For example I have another file as `foo.py`:

```
foo = 'foo'
```

And I use IronPython hosting API to execute `bar.py`:

```
from foo import foo
print foo
```

If I make changes to `bar.py` then without exiting the host application I can see my changes made take effect. But if I edit `foo.py` then I have to reboot my application to see the changes. I've already enabled `Debug` in the options but it does not help.

Please advice. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, imported modules are cached by the ScriptEngine instance. You'll have to create a new engine instance if you want to reload cached modules automatically. There's currently no way to disable that and always reload modules.

An option to disable the caching behaviour isn't a bad idea; [open an issue](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create) so that it's on the radar. Patches are even better, of course.

Comment: 10 years later, the issue still exists